# Laravel Homestead: This webpage is not available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, virtualbox

Newbie to laravel homestead and vagrant and struggling to get my site to load in the browser.  Everything looks as though its running, successfully ran vagrant up.

When i type url http://local.bookings.com:8000/ I receive message "This webpage is not available"

I should point out however that I am on Windows 7 and have nothing visibly running in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.

**Homestead.yaml**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: c:/Users/me/.ssh/github_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/me/.ssh/github_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/documents/projects/bookings
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: local.bookings.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/bookings/public


variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

**hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1       local.bookings.com
```

Comment: The URL you're typing in is local.bookings.app but your hosts file has local.bookings.com?

Comment: This is just a typo in the example sorry.  It is .com in the URL

Comment: I should point out also that it seems like it is taking forever to connect

Comment: Could be a BIOS issue as described here http://laravel.io/forum/05-18-2014-trouble-getting-homestead-to-start-in-windows

Comment: Great, that's helped, although I now get a no input file specified message

Answer (score 2):

Edit the host file as

`192.168.10.10  local.bookings.com`

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, make sure you run homestead up or vagrant up and change the host file to 192.168.10.10 local.bookings.com